# open file with string that has multiple variables

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, urlopen

I can get the text file when I set airport to one variable. However, how can I get the text files for multiple airport codes and display the information?

```
airport = 'KSFO, KSJC, KOAK'

for metar in urlopen('http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/%s.TXT' %airport):
        metar = metar.decode("utf-8")
        if "%s" %airport in metar:
            print metar
```

Comment: You need to split the string on `comma(,)` and use the individual element from the list obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to fetch the weather observations for each of those airports, you could use:

```
from urllib import urlopen
airports = 'KSFO, KSJC, KOAK'

for airport_code in airports.split(","):
    for metar in urlopen('http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/%s.TXT' % airport_code.strip()):
        metar = metar.decode("utf-8")
        print metar
```

For me, the output is:

> 2012/10/30 07:56
> KSFO 300756Z 29005KT 10SM FEW001 13/11 A3006 RMK AO2 SLP178 T01280111 402110117
>
> 2012/10/30 07:53
> KSJC 300753Z AUTO 00000KT 10SM CLR 10/ A3005 RMK AO2 SLP175 T0100 402060089 $
>
> 2012/10/30 08:14
> KOAK 300814Z 06003KT 10SM OVC004 13/12 A3007 RMK AO2

Comment: you should indent the last two lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
airport = 'KSFO, KSJC, KOAK'

for airports in airport.split(', '):
    for metar in urlopen('http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/%s.TXT' %airports):
            metar = metar.decode("utf-8")
            if "%s" %airports in metar:
                print metar
```

Basiclly we split the `airport` variable where `,` (a comma and then a space) is the separator into three different variables with:

```
`airport.split(', ')`
```

Comment: It prints the first airport code but the second two don't work because there is a space in the link.